# Java write application log on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver

I deployed an Java application on GAE and now I'm finding the way to view application log on GAE.

I read this guide:
[Reading and Writing Application Logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/logs/)

but it doesn't work.
I want to view my application log on Stackdriver Logging on Google Cloud Platform screen like below:

[Stackdriver Logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWryW.png)

Does anyone configure to show application log on GAE. Could you suggest me a solution ?

My configuration:

1. appengine-web.xml

[src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tda0V.png)

2. logging.properties

[logging.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg2KG.png)

3. Write log code using:
   I'm using `private static final java.util.logging.Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CategoryResource.class.getName());`

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNPJG.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Share the code you tried using and any setup steps you took *here in the question*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated step by step that I configured in my project.

Comment: written/typed code should not be in an image

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation you listed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/logs) literally does exactly what you want. It surfaces the logs in the log viewer on your Google Cloud Console. I have confirmed that it still works.

Please read [this part](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/logs/#reading_logs_in_the_console) carefully and see if you are still not able to find the logs.

If that's still the case, provide us with your full code on how you setup the logging to include all the steps in the documentation. If the steps are followed, it should work.